# How to give condition in image tag using angular 6?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular6

My webpage contains,

```
      <ng-container *ngFor="let horizontal of categories">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let horizontalval of horizontal.items;let i=index">
          <button [ngClass]="{'selected-color' : i==selectedIndex }" 
          [ngStyle]="{'padding-top':horizontal.items[i].title==='Business'?'2.56%':(horizontal.items[i].title==='Plat' ? '2.56%':null)}"type="submit" class="btn1"  [id]="horizontal.items[i].title"
           (click)="changeImage(id);">
           <img [src]= horizontal.items[i].icon alt="image not found" class="icon"/>
           {{ horizontal.items[i].title }}
          </button>
        </ng-container>
```

My ts file:

```
 changeImage(option){
if(option == "Trans"){


    this.imgDefault = 'imgChange';
    console.log("this.imgDefault :",this.imgDefault);
}
 else if(option == "Col"){

    this.imgDefault = 'imgChange1';
    console.log("this.imgDefault :",this.imgDefault1);
}
else if(option == "Business"){
    this.imgDefault = 'imgChange2';
    console.log("this.imgDefault :",this.imgDefault2);
}

}
```

So in my css I have kept the images which needs to be changed onclick of the button.

```
.imgChange{
background-image: url('../assets/Trans_2.png');
color:blue;
 }
.imgChange1{
background-image: url('../assets/Trans_3.png');
color:blue;
 }
 .imgChange2{
background-image: url('../assets/Trans_4.png');
color:blue;
 }
```

How can I give condition in img tag, so that onclick of a button to change the image?

Comment: First of all, make your decision how you want to display the image. Either by img src or setting the background image by css ?

Comment: @Sai, accept answer if you found one.

Answer (score 2):

You should add `image` in a `div` as below:-

### ts

```
      imgDefault = 'imgChange'; <-- default;

changeImage(option){
if(option == "Trans"){


    this.imgDefault = 'imgChange';
    console.log("this.imgDefault :",this.imgDefault);
}
 else if(option == "Col"){

    this.imgDefault = 'imgChange1';
    console.log("this.imgDefault :",this.imgDefault1);
}
else if(option == "Business Process Re-engineering"){
    this.imgDefault = 'imgChange2';
    console.log("this.imgDefault :",this.imgDefault2);
}

}
```

### .html

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let horizontal of categories">
 <ng-container *ngFor="let horizontalval of horizontal.items;let i=index">
 <button [ngClass]="{'selected-color' : i==selectedIndex }" 
 [ngStyle]="{'padding-top':horizontal.items[i].title==='Business'?'2.56%':(horizontal.items[i].title==='Plat' ? '2.56%':null)}"type="submit" class="btn1"  [id]="horizontal.items[i].title"click)="changeImage(id);">

{{ horizontal.items[i].title }}
 </button>
 </ng-container>  
</ng-container>  

<div [ngClass]="imgDefault"></div>
```

Link:-  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-sqemmd?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: Instead of   <ng-container>. You should use  <div>

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the same. But Im not able to get the image.

Comment: Is this.imgDefault  is getting changed onclick?

Comment: Yes, It needs to be changed on onclick of the button

Comment: Inspect the div and check whether image is getting loaded on network tab

Comment: @Sai, Please check Stackblitz link.

Comment: Its same as mentioned in above stackblitz link.

Comment: Sorry , please check this link, can't the html part be simplified like this
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-yzk5v8?file=app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add `class` names based on the conditions - you are trying to add images from `css` replace the `img` tag as `div` which will render background image based on the `class` applied

Make sure if you want your images in the loop, if not move your `div` outside `*ngFor`

```
<div [class.imgChange]="imgDefault === 'imgChange'" 
     [class.imgChange1]="imgDefault === 'imgChange1'"
     [class.imgChange2]="imgDefault === 'imgChange2'" ></div>
```

This will add all your classes based on the condition and the `div` will render the `img`  - Hope this works Happy coding !!